# Proof limit and integral of sequence of continuous functions interchangeable

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I want to proof the following theorem.

> Let $f_n: \Omega \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be a sequence of continuous functions, $ [a,b] \subset \Omega \,$, $f_n \to f $ uniformly convergent on $\Omega \,$, $f$ on $[a,b]$ integrable.
>
> $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b (f_n(x)) \,dx = \int_a^b (\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)) \, dx$$

(Note that integrability is already given in this version of the theorem.)

I’m not really sure how to show this at all. What must be proven, so that I can interchange limits and Integrals?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note that if $\sup\{\lvert f(x)-f_n(x)\rvert\mid x\in[a,b]\}<\epsilon$, then
$$
\left\lvert\int_a^bf(x)\,dx-\int_a^bf_n(x)\,dx\right\rvert\leq\int_a^b\left\lvert f(x)-f_n(x)\right\rvert\,dx<\epsilon(b-a).
$$

Comment: Thanks! I put in an additional sentence in the question that I don’t really know how to go about this at all. Not just one step but generally, what’s the rough idea... or how do you go about it? For example where in you hint does the limit from above come in?

Comment: You seem to be overthinking it.  The left hand side is just some sequence $(a_n)$, and the right hand side is just some value $a$.  You need to show that $a_n\to a$ as $n\to\infty$.  What I've shown you is a way of showing that $\lvert a_n-a\rvert$ is small IF $\lvert f(x)-f_n(x)\rvert$ is *uniformly* small.  And you have uniform convergence, so you can make that true by choosing $n$ large enough. So, let $\epsilon>0$ be given, ...